# Surface Mount vs. PTH Components For Production

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, surface-mount, production

I'm a hobbyist who has developed a product which uses ~20 PTH components. The device is essentially an Arduino UNO with some extra driver ICs and LEDs. I have had quite a lot of positive feedback on the product and am considering re-designing it so that I can put it into production.

I was wondering what technology was best for automated/volume production? I've noticed that several companies use both surface mount and PTH components on their boards, Arduino being an example. How do the board designers make a decision on what technology to use? Size isn't really an issue for this product, the existing board using PTH components is a quarter of the size of it's container.

Comment: What do you mean by "volume"? How many of them will be produced?

Comment: It's difficult to say, for the purposes of this question shall we say hundreds rather than thousands.

Comment: First off, identify your fabrication house, then see what it'd cost for them to populate and solder your boards, with either TH, SMT or a mix. In general, I have found that a mix costs the most. Also, for places with low manual labor cost, TH can be massively cheaper than SMT for production orders of a handful of panels (say a few hundred boards, depending on how many you can put in a panel). From personal experience: In India, the cost for small 2-layer boards with full population plus soldering and testing is about 1:15 favoring TH. This includes component cost, excluding exotic/rare parts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend you check out the excellent **EEVblog** tutorial videos [part one](http://www.eevblog.com/2010/11/15/eevblog-127-pcb-design-for-manufacture-tutorial/) and [part two](http://www.eevblog.com/2012/01/25/eevblog-239-pcb-design-for-manufacture-part-2/) covering PCB design for manufacturing. You'll not only find the answers to your component selection questions above, you'll get a ton of suggestions and advice about a half-dozen other critical issues you might not have thought of yet.

They're a long stream at about an hour apiece, but *totally* worth it!

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I'll take a look at those videos tonight. Hopefully they'll give me some insight!